# Отличие между интерпретатором и компилятором

Tags: компилятор, интерпретатор

Объясните, в чем разница, пытался гуглить - из прочитанного ничего не понял!

Comment: Тогда откуда уверенность, что поймешь объяснение здесь?

Comment: интерпретатор читает входной код, распознает языковые конструкции и на основании их выполняет работу. компилятор сначала интерпретирует текст на основании его формирует исполняемый машинный код, который потом просто выполняется ОС или еще чем-то. скомпилировать достаточно один раз, получить исполняемый файл, и далее работать с ним. Интерпретатор же каждый раз работает с исходным файлом.

Comment: к примеру php - обрабатывается интерпритатором или javascript обрабатывается компилятором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилятор анализирует и преобразует весь код программы на языке высокого уровня в код низкого уровня (близкий к машинному коду).
Интерпретатор анализирует каждую команду отдельно и сразу выполняет ее